# Segmentation fault strtok

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

i'm trying to understand why this code give me a segmentation fault!
`research` is a string and it's printing my tokens but after that i have a segmentation fault.
Could you help me please ?

```
char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
strcpy(buf, research.c_str());

int n = 0;
const char * token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {};

for (n = 0; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
{
    if (n == 0) token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITERS);
    else token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITERS);

    if (!token[++n]) break;

    printf("%s\n", token[n]);
}
```

Comment: What if there are not `MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE` tokens?

Comment: In addition to Blue Moon's comment above, you also seem to be adding 1 to n twice - once in the for loop and once on the break line.  I don't know if this is intended or not?

Comment: It's hard to believe that this should even print the first tokens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No pre-increment

```
if (!token[n]) break;
```

Always use strncpy when copying to a fixed length char array - not strcpy.

Comment: +1, but I suggest: "`n` is already incremented in your for-loop" instead of "No pre-increment"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you approach this issue in a really complicated way, and therefore seem to lose oversight.

```
char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE] = {0}; /* Intialise the array properly. */
strncpy(buf, research.c_str(), MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE - 1); /* Take care to not overflow the target. */

size_t n = 0; /* size_t is the proper type to index arrays. */
const char * token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {};

token[n] = strtok(buf, DELIMITERS);
while (token[n]  && (n < (MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE - 1))
{
  n++;

  token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITERS);

  printf("%s\n", token[n]);
}
```